# AOT issue with message Attempting to JIT compile method with Pinvoke on Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, c++, ios, xamarin, pinvoke

I am facing an AOT issue with message Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper managed-to-native) ;...wrapper_aot_native (object)' while running with --aot-only.

I have a structure containing methods pointers that should be initialized by a native function (called LoadContext), this struct seems like that :

```
[StructLayout (LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct WrapperContext
{
    public int ctxVersion;

    public unsafe GetLibraryVersionXDelegate GetLibraryVersion;

    public unsafe GetLibraryDateXDelegate GetLibraryDate;

    public unsafe InitCallbackTableXDelegate InitCallbackTable;

    .....
}
```

when I call the LoadContext native method that should initialize the WrapperContext struct, the below exception was thrown by the runtime :

> Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper managed-to-native) XXXXX.XXXXXX.XXXXX.GetLibraryVersionXDelegate:wrapper_aot_native (object)' while running with --aot-only. See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations for more information.

Trying to resolve the issue, I created another structure that contains the exact same field list, but replacing the delegate types with IntPtr:

```
[StructLayout (LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct WrapperContext2
{
    public int ctxVersion;

    public IntPtr GetLibraryVersionXDelegate GetLibraryVersion;

    public IntPtr GetLibraryDateXDelegate GetLibraryDate;

    public IntPtr InitCallbackTableXDelegate InitCallbackTable;

    .....
}
```

For now, the call to my native LoadContext works correctly and I am getting a pointer for each function, but when trying to convert function pointers to their delegates representation using Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(), the exact same exception was thrown by the runtime:

> Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper managed-to-native) XXXXX.XXXXXX.XXXXX.GetLibraryVersionXDelegate:wrapper_aot_native (object)' while running with --aot-only. See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations for more information.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved the issue by adding UnmanagedFunctionPointer attribute on each delegate definition :

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public unsafe delegate IntPtr GetLibraryVersionXDelegate();

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public unsafe delegate IntPtr GetLibraryDateXDelegate();
```

Hope this helps other guys.

Comment: I have same issue, but it says type or namespace UnmanagedFunctionPointer not found. Any idea?